# Table Edit js with codeigniter

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to use for the first time the plugin **jquery.tabledit.js** with codeigniter. The author gives clear details of how to use it. My issue is I don't know how to pass the rows data from js function to my controller ? The way i try can't work. How  can I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
 <table class="uptade-table">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>id</th>
     <th>price</th>
     <th>total</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
   </tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>345</td>
    <td>46456</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
    $('.uptade-table').Tabledit({
        url: "<?=base_url('update')?>",
        columns:{
            identifier:[0, "id"],
            editable:[
                [1, 'price'], 
                [2, 'total']
            ]
        },
    });
});
```

// Controller

```
public function update()
{
    $id=$this->input->post('id');
    $price=$this->input->post('price');
    $total=$this->input->post('total');
    $data = array
    (
        'price'=>$price,
        'total'=>$total
    );
    $this->model_admin->update($id,$data);
}
```

MODEL

```
 public function update($id,$data){
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  $this->db->update('table', $data);
   }
```

Comment: what is monto ?

Comment: please paste your model and html code also

Answer (score 0):

There is no id your in table to update the table row

Comment: According the online example of this plugin the first td has the id value  and we grab it in the function " identifier:[0, "id"],". If I misunderstand let me know. please  ,https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/#examples

Comment: @Diasline, there is input hidden id in the example, please inspect it, you can find it in browser